# How do I properly call startSpinner() on an ons-button in OnsenUI version 1?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, onsen-ui

I've got an ons-button element

`<ons-button modifier="large--cta" ng-click="login($event, input.email, input.password)">Log In</ons-button>`

And a function (login) that is attempting to use the startSpinner() method of OnsenUI's ons-button to start a spinner on the button to show the user that the app is working on their request.

I've tried the following without success. None of these functions are defined per the console.

`event.currentTarget.startSpinner()`

`event.target.startSpinner()`

`startSpinner(event.currentTarget)`

How do I go about starting a spinner on the button from a function called via ng-click?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is firstly to define a service as follows:

```
app.factory('service', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
  return {
    showSpinnerAuto : function() {
        modal.show();
        setTimeout('modal.hide()', 10000);
    },
    showSpinnerTimer : function(timer) {
        modal.show();
        setTimeout('modal.hide()', timer);
    },
    showSpinner : function() {
        modal.show();
    },
    hideSpinner : function() {
        modal.hide();
    }
  };

}]);
```

You also need to define spinner model in your view as below:

```
<ons-modal var="modal">
    <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-pulse"></i>
    <br><br>loading...
</ons-modal>
```

And finally, you can call show/hide Spinner in your controller as follows:

```
app.controller('Controller', ['$rootScope', '$scope', 'service', function($rootScope, $scope, service) {
    service.showSpinner(); //show
    service.hideSpinner(); //hide
    service.showSpinnerAuto(); //show and then hide automatically
}]);
```

Hope this help!